# How do you determine if a relation is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Suppose I have the relation P such that $$ x P y $$ iff

$$ x = y^2 $$

How do I determine whether or not the relation is transitive?

Comment: $xPy$ and $yPz \implies x = y^2 = z^4$ so $x \ne z^2$ and thus $xPz$ is false.

Answer (score 2):

A relation $R$ over a set $X$ is said to be transitive if, for all $a, b, c \in X$, $aRb$ and $bRc$ $\Rightarrow$ $aRc$.

For your relation $P$, taking $x = y^2$ and $y = z^2$, we see that $x = (z^2)^2 \neq z^2$.

Thus, $xPy$ and $yPz$ does not imply $xPz$, and $P$ is not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

It is not transitive because $16P4$ and $4P2$ hold, while $16 P 2$ is false.

Comment: Is there a general way to look at these?

Comment: @Alex: Try to understand the relation by trying out a few examples. By doing so, you may be more convinced that the property is true, or otherwise find a counterexample.